# Compiling the Aruco Library?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, augmented-reality, surface

I'm using virtual studio to create an augmented reality system used solely for detecting the orientation and skew of surfaces. I am new to C++ and wanted to ask if someone could provide instruction on how to implement the aruco library into visual studio.

I have successfully implemented the opencv library into visual studio, and have used cmake to extract the aruco library to my documents folder.

Thanks,

Niall

Answer (score 0):

If you install the latest version of opencv (3.1) the aruco library is already included.
Simply "#include opencv2/aruco.hpp>"

Check this for details: http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d53/aruco_8hpp.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: If this was true in the past, it is absolutely not true anymore. ArUco is included in OpenCV-contrib, but it is not included in OpenCV. You will either need to get the ArUco library files from OpenCV-contrib and compile it, or you will need to get the ArUco library files elsewhere. 
I would love to see anyone demonstrate that ArUco is included in plain OpenCV, because it simply isn't, and "#include opencv2/aruco.hpp>" will fail to compile unless the user takes a lot of extra steps. Advice like this is extremely unhelpful, and distracting to people looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Aruco 1.3.0 also has CMakeLists.txt.
Run CMake-GUI and create your own VS project as you did for openCV.